# Destructing props in react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am facing issue with lint error on destructing props assignment. Since i am new i dont know how to do it with function in props.

this is my function where is it assigned:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.props.inputChange(e.target.value);
}
```

i am passing change to parent element (lifting the state up) so i have now function in properties where the changes into input box are reflected.

Please how can i make it destructive within passing this parameter (e.target.value)?

Thanks,

## UPDATE:

After answers and some research i finally did it following:

```
handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
  const { inputChange } = this.props;
  inputChange(value);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'make it destructive' ?

Comment: If you mean destructuring in the parameter, Mose's answer is correct

Comment: yes that is what i meant. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Destructuring nested arguments:**

```
handleChange({target: {value}}) {
 this.props.inputChange(value);
}
```

Comment: actually this throws me :  error  Must use destructuring props assignment                                react/destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

//**Parent component**

```
changedHandler(event) {
    const value = event.target.value
}

<ComponentChild changed={this.changedHandler}>
```

//**Child component**

```
<input type="text" onChange={props.changed}>
```